# CSS blur, borders blend with background

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, filter, blur

When I add a blur (CSS) to my image, and put it in a div, to keep straight borders, the image blends with the other elements:
My code is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2t-Ql_mj7hRU0NHZkpDbHZPWWM/edit?usp=sharing

How can I have straight borders, without blending?
I only have this issue with Google Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to it adopting the color behind it, then you would need to provide it with a `background-color`, but if you just want it to be a square instead then try this edit of your original code: http://jsfiddle.net/Incredulous/6V9ua/

I've removed your duplicate CSS for the `img` selector and added a `px` to the end of your -20. Your CSS now looks like this:

```
body{
    background:red;
    text-align:center;
    }
img{
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px); 
    -moz-filter: blur(20px); 
    filter: blur(20px);
    margin:-20px;
    }
div{
    overflow:hidden;
    display:table;
    background-color:white;
    }
```

I added the `display:table;` to make your div fit the content inside it and the `background-color:white;` to remove the bleeding of the red on the edges.

Comment: Doesn't work when I add "-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)" :(

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2t-Ql_mj7hRM0ZhWmVYRHUtdzA/edit  If you toggle the translate in the inspector, you can clearly see the difference

Comment: In my chrome I see a more pronounced blur with the `translateZ(0)` on. Increase the value of the blur and then toggle the `translateZ(0)` you will see that it is still working in both instances, but at a much lower strength.